# Book for particles physics

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Particle physics getting started](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312/particle-physics-getting-started)

I'm looking for a book that introduces the building blocks refer to the standard model for a course in nuclear physics. There are good books on this?

Comment: Do you want the book to be popular or technical? And if technical, on what level (e.g. are you already familiar with QFT?)?

Comment: I'm an italian student in theoretical physics and I'll follow a course of QFT in the next didactic period. I'm now follow a course of nuclear physics in wich there is an introduction to the elementary particles physics and standard model and I'm looking for an introductory book to this argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest [Griffiths](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471603864) and/or [Kane](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201624605). Read the reviews to see whether this is the kind of books you are after.

There is also a pretty nice (if quite popular) Flip Tanedo's [blog series](http://blogs.uslhc.us/lets-draw-feynman-diagams) on the topic. If you like that, I also recommend the rest of his posts $-$ they're pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

[Particles and Nuclei](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540366830) is an excellent book, without derivations, but gets important ideas and results across. Then, a good but very short (at ~300 pages) introduction to the Standard Model is [An Introduction to the Standard Model of Particle Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521852498). Then there is Zee's outstanding [Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691140340), it has short, readable chapters, although it's almost certainly useless in terms of studying for tests for you course unless the prof. specifically uses this book. Good luck!