# Nuclear physics... for a chemist

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, education

Unfortunately, for chemists, are curriculum is (usually) not *as* rigorous in the mathematics and physics as I would’ve liked. This (in my humble opinion) is a disservice to those looking to explore more physical areas of chemistry.

As an aspiring nuclear chemist, I need some recommendations for a good place to start to learn nuclear physics at a level that is beneficial for a chemist. Preferably books that are more suited for the autodidact with limited contact with outside resources that can aid in my studies.

Additionally if anyone thinks I should look into any books/subjects that may not be present in a chemists curriculum but is necessary to this subject, that would be appreciated along with the necessary math required for each.

I’ve only really just begun graduate studies so advanced classes in either field is essentially zero

Edit:

My (relevant) curriculum -

1. Thermodynamics
2. Quantum Mechanics
3. Up to multi variable calculus
4. Linear algebra
5. Differential equations
6. Mechanics
7. Electromagnetism (freshman level)

Not sure about specific topics to cover in nuclear physics so a more broad introduction is preferred for a first book.

Comment: You may need to be more specific about what topics you're hoping to cover unless you're just looking for an introduction to nuclear physics, especially since people on this site may not know exactly what "subjects that may not be present in a chemists curriculum" involves.

Comment: Also a nuclear chemist is a chemist. It is not very clear what your interests are. I suggest to discuss this within your institution. Cross posting (if allowed) to Chemistry SE might be an option.

Comment: Can you clarify what your exposure to electromagnetism is? Like, at the university physics 2 level or the senior level physics major course? The difference between electromagnetism at the freshman level and the graduate level is immense. If you can tell us what your exposure to it is, it'll help us gauge your mathematical background

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437765/2451, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1267/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @PaulPhy freshman level. Very very basic

Comment: @Alchimista I think I’m just so new to the subjects that I don’t even know where to start

Comment: @Alchimista, Re, "Nuclear chemist is a chemist," True, but probably the majority of "ordinary" chemists don't spend too much time thinking about the consequences of some atoms within a sample/substance/solution/material suddenly changing their atomic number.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that it right my point. I am not dividing science or scientists into categories. But professional figures. A nuclear chemist might be well be doing just chemistry. Like in waste treatment. If OP want to attain a deep insight, he should contact someone at his her institution. From the text is difficult to know what she/he is willing to achieve.

Comment: @Alchimista sure, I will definitely ask around my institution, however the sample size is much more limited then the internet. The opinions I may received here will be taken into account with those received from people I know personally.

Comment: The MIT open course ware has several related to nuclear physics, https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=science&subcat=physics&spec=nuclearphysics ,, there is one an introduction to nuclear and particle physics https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-701-introduction-to-nuclear-and-particle-physics-spring-2004/

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193118/226902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while there are related posts for learning nuclear physics, I will answer this one because you also ask about the background to going into nuclear studies. My background is in high energy physics, but I think I can at least point you in the right direction for self study. The first things you should get under your belt are a good study ofelectromagnetism, quantum mechanics, and particle physics. My recommendations for all of these at the upper undergraduate level are written by the same infamous author: Griffiths. Don't just read these books. So much learning is done by trying to work out the problems in the books.
Here are the links for each of the respective books by Griffiths:

[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Electrodynamics-David-J-Griffiths/dp/1108420419/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&qid=1605537882&refinements=p_27%3ADavid+Griffiths&s=books&sr=1-2&text=David+Griffiths](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108420419)

[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Quantum-Mechanics-David-Griffiths/dp/1107189632/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&qid=1605537882&refinements=p_27%3ADavid+Griffiths&s=books&sr=1-3&text=David+Griffiths](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107189632)

[https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Elementary-Particles-David-Griffiths/dp/3527406018/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&qid=1605537882&refinements=p_27%3ADavid+Griffiths&s=books&sr=1-5&text=David+Griffiths](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3527406018)

Then I think it would be beneficial for you to at least dabble in quantum field theory. Before you do that though, you should really be exposed to graduate level quantum mechanics. My go to text at that level is Sakurai/Napolitano's book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Quantum-Mechanics-2nd-Sakurai/dp/0805382917](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805382917)

Be sure to get the newer edition which has a chapter on relativistic quantum mechanics. This is a heavy read though. It would probably take two semester to read through, so you might be able to get by with a lighter readying of it. For someone not looking to do theoretical physics, I would suggest learning quantum field theory from a book like "QFT for the Gift Amateur" by Lancaster/Blundell:

[https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Field-Theory-Gifted-Amateur/dp/019969933X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019969933X)

So finally, I can not personally recommend the text by Krane because I have not read it myself. However, every other post related to learning nuclear physics recommends the textbook by Kenneth Krane.

[https://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Nuclear-Physics-Kenneth-Krane/dp/047180553X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047180553X)

Best of luck in your self study!