# Can a kaon decay into 4 pions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model, mesons

Since a Kaon's wavefunction is composed of $K_S$ and $K_L$ which are CP-even and CP-odd respectively. The Kaon can decay into $\pi \pi \pi \pi$ through $K_S$ since the 4 pions have CP-parity $= (-1)^4 = 1$

Is this just like the explanation as to why it can decay into 2 pions?

Also, any recommendations on another book for particle physics other than Griffiths? It is really bad.

Comment: There's a list of other books [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/312/books-for-particle-physics-and-the-standard-model). At this level I think Griffiths has the clearest explanations by far, though. There are even clearer books, but they're pitched at a much higher level.

Answer (score 3):

A K0 has a mass of ~497 MeV. The pion ~140 MeV.

Four pions 4x140=560 MeV. Thus four pions cannot in any way  be produced from the rest mass of a K0, even if all four are at rest.