# Beginning particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, education

I wanted to start learning particle physics and I have studied all classical Field theories. I found out that I should read Introduction to particle physics by Griffiths. But when I started reading I did not understand it. It said

> For example, in relativity, energy and momentum are always conserved, but (rest) mass is not. Thus the decay Δ gives ρ +π is perfectly acceptable, even though the Δ weighs more than the sum of ρ +π Such a process would not be possible in classical mechanics.

Now I did not understand the Δ gives π and ρ part at all and what they mean. Have I started with a wrong book or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312/2451 and links therein.

Comment: To reopen this post (v2) consider to remove the res. recom. part/educational advices and just ask the actual physics question alone.

Comment: Mate Im not asking for a book recommendation.Im asking if I have missed something

Comment: Hi BlackSusanoo. Sentences such as, e.g., "Have I started with a wrong book?" gives this impression.

Comment: $\Delta$, $\rho$, and $\pi$ are three kinds of particles. In relativistic physics, some of the mass-energy of the $\Delta$ can turn into kinetic energy of the $\rho$ and $\pi$, which combined have less mass-energy than the $\Delta$.

Comment: Related meta site post: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12969/2451