# Recommend some advanced books on the standard model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, education

I am now reading Weinberg quantum field theory volume 1. But the notations are almost impossible to read for me. I completed Griffiths elementary particles book and Srednicki quantum field theory. So I need some advanced book on standard model.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

A very good, and modern, introduction to the theory of the standard model is given by Schwart's book *Quantum field theory and the standard model*. A more in depth book on the dynamics of the standard model is the classical book by Donoghue, Glowich and Holstein. There are many more honorable mentions, but i think that this is a good start.

Comment: Considering OP has read Srednicki, they may skip a great deal of Schwartz

Comment: @NiharKarve Oh yeah, that's true. For a moment the contents of Srednicki slipped out of my mind! But the second advice still remains.

Comment: In addition to all the books mentioned in the above link, I would also suggest Cheng &Li gauge theory of elementary particle physics and Langacker The Standard Model and beyond. Cheng & Li is somewhat dated, but it provides a nice in depth analysis of how to get to the standard model.